# How to draw a large image in small size with new context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, image

![enter image description here][1]By using the following code, I am able to draw a large image in small form, But new one image have their superview context or in other other word new image show in centre of new `image` but have a large white background to cover up large imageSize.

So, Actual image size is same as large image but I want to remove the extra white space.

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(largeImage.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                     [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake((largeImage.size.width-80)/2, (largeImage.size.height-60)/2, 60, 80);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    [largeImage drawInRect:rectangle];

    UIImage *smallSizeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Finally , I am getting `smallSizeimage` with a lot of white background. I want to change their white background without loosing the image quality.
Please guide me..

Comment: set that imageview's background colour as clear color.

Comment: I haven't showing image in image view ,Just select large image and draw in small image

Comment: I want draw  smallsizeImage of rectangle size as mention in code without white part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating the process mate.

I will post below an explanation to your problem,
Since I'm not a native english speaker, if some of my explanations aren't really clear, tell me, and I'll try to rephrase them.
If you are just interested in a working code, without any of my explanations, just scroll to the bottom.

First of all, your main issues are the following two:
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(largeImage.size, NO, 0);` and `[largeImage drawInRect:rectangle];`

In `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` you suppose to set the new graphics context you are interested in, meaning, the new image size, and not the large one, as you are doing in your example.

Second, the `UIImage` instance method `[yourImage drawInRect:yourRect` is in your coordinate system of the graphics context, and not the coordinate system of the view.
Meaning, you suppose to treat it as a rectangle which begins at `(0, 0)` and is the size of your image.

After explaining to you the mistakes you've had, I'll post 2 variations of code.
One is to make a small image out of your original one, which you'll see in a second how much of a simple process that is.
And the second one is a modified version of your code above, since I don't know what you are using it to, could be that you do need the use of some of the other things from you original code.

To resize an image:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(60,80); // Our new image size  
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 80); // Our 'work' rect in out image context
// Begin a new image context with the new size we want
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);  
// Draw our image to our new rect  
[largeImage drawInRect:newRect];  
// Create a new UIImage from our new context  
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
// End our image context  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And that's it!

If you still need to use some of the stuff from your original code, Here is a modified version of it:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(60, 80);  
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 80);  
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);  
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];  
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                 [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, newRect);
CGContextClip(context); // EDIT- this is what we were missing
CGContextStrokePath(context);
[largeImage drawInRect:newRect];
UIImage *smallSizeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Good luck mate!

EDIT- Check out the code above for the edit.
Basically, what you and I have both missed in your code, is that, even tough you create a rounded context by using `CGContextAddEllipseInRect()`, we don't have a call to `CGContextClip()` to actually 'clipping' the context in our ellipse shape.
Now your image should be 'rounded'.

Comment: Hey Mate,your solutions seems working but whenever we dropped the size to (30,50) then resolution dropped.Please advise how we can retain the HD resolution other then this your solutions works perfect and i am giving you full mark.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);  
// Draw our image to our new rect  
[largeImage drawInRect:newRect];  
// Create a new UIImage from our new context  
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();...using this code image drawn in small size but resolution dropped.Kindly advise!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think that your whole approach was incorrect in the first place. In the example in your question, you were trying to create a new image with smaller resolution. if `largeImage` is, let's say, 120pt x 160x, `smallSizeImage` is half the size (60pt x 80pt), that's why the resolution 'dropped', because this code is to 'drop' the resolution. If what you want is for the image to have the same resolution, but just appear smaller on screen, just change the frame of the image view that presents it.

Comment: If you'll show some code of how you present the image on the screen, I could point you to what needs to be changed.

Comment: Ami, we have attached the image which we got after applying masking.We are applying resizing on this attached image to achieve smaller size (30x40) with the same resolution.

Comment: Could you also add the code you are using to present it on the screen?

Comment: UIBezierPath *path;
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480) {
        
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(26,32,originalImage.size.width-52,288)];
    }
    else{
        
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(26,61,originalImage.size.width-52,318)];
    }

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, 0);
   [path addClip];
   UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 52, 65));
   [originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
   [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
  
    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return maskedImage;

Comment: Ami, above two comments code we have used to get the masked image.

Comment: I understand, but what code do you use to actually show it on screen? you probably pass it to a `UIImageView` variable...

Comment: We are saving that image in PhotoGallery and then from there we are sharing it through iMessage or etc..that is what we are doing.

Comment: UIImage *circularImg =[[UIImage alloc] init];
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);

Comment: [self.library saveImage:circularImg
                    toAlbum:@"Album Name"
                 completion: nil
                    failure:^(NSError *error) {
                        if (error!=nil) {
                            
                            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Image is not saved!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                            [alert show];
                        }
                        else{
                            
                        }
                    }];

Comment: Ami,above two comments code we are applying after masking n resizing process to save that image in Photogallery.Hope this will help you to determine the exact issue.

Comment: Ohh....sorry...Now I understand correctly...try changing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 2.0);` and see if it looks better. This last parameter is the scale factor. The number of pixels is determined by multiplying the size of the image by the scale factor, meaning, the first parameter with the last.

Comment: Yes we tried it and nothing much improvement notices by setting scale factor to 2.0.We have tried 0,1, 2 all cases and in all resolution dropped.

Comment: I've been trying to play with different conversion methods, such as using CoreGraphics and CoreImage but the example above seems to give the best result...I don't know if the level of detail you are trying to achieve can be achieved at those low resolutions. If you try to scale the picture to those resolutions in some other non-code method, using the mac's Preview for example, could you achieve the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for helping us, We just want to resize a large image in small image, But on resizing we are dropping the image resolution .Second approach we have implement by drawing a large image in new react as you have noticed in the code which we have post in our question .But new image have a outer white background without any image resolution dropped ,So Please advice us how to remove the outer white image by changing context without loosing image resolution.

Comment: Sorry. as I've mentioned, I'm not a native english speaker so took me a while to completely understand, but now I think I do. If I now (finally) understand correctly, the outer white image you are referring is that your image is square, and therefore 'padded' with white, but you need it to be round. I'll edit my code in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(largeImage.size, NO, 0);
```

with this:

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(small.size, NO, 0);
```

Furhermore here it is a method that i call to resize images:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{

CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(100, 100);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Comment: By using your approach image resolutions dropped a lot.Is there any way by which we can retain the resolution like other app does for example "Emoji app" does it,